# Codeblocks Error 'Project File does not Exist'

Tags: codeblocks

When I have some other project open in CodeBlocks and I try to open a new project into the workspace by double clicking on the .cbp file from the explorer, it gives an error "Project File does not exist...". But the same project when I open using File->Open Project, it opens just fine.
[image: The Error Message]
How do I open the CodeBlocks project externally using the .cbp file without getting this error?

Comment: it happens when we set the codeblocks to open projects in same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try
a) Close all instances of CodeBlocks, then try to reopen the project.
OR
b) Open the project file by the menu File->Open

Answer (score -2):

The path of your new project is too long.

Comment: And hence, what is the solution? It was working fine with me in 13.12